# Sending multiple actions from Effect, on server response, using action.payload in all of them

Tags: rxjs, angular7, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

What currently works with one action:

```
@Effect()
addAssignment$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(assignmentActions.AssignmentsActionTypes.AddAssignment),
exhaustMap((action) => {
        return this.assignmentDataService.addOrUpdateAssignment([action.payload]).pipe(
            map((assignment) => {
                return new assignmentActions.AddAssignmentSuccess(assignment);
            })
        );
    }));
```

How I'm trying to refactor this:

```
@Effect()
updateAssignment$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(assignmentActions.AssignmentsActionTypes.UpdateAssignment),
map((action) => {
  return action.payload;
}),
switchMap((payload) => {
  return this.assignmentDataService.addOrUpdateAssignment([payload.postData]);
}),
switchMap((res) => {
  return [
    new assignmentActions.LastUpdatedAssignmentPost(action.payload.postData),
    new assignmentActions.LastUpdatedAssignment(action.payload.mergedData),
    new assignmentActions.UpdateAssignmentSuccess(action.payload.mergedData),
  ];
})
);
```

How ever ofcourse **action.payload.mergedData** & **action.payload.postData** are not available in the last switchMap, and since im quite noob to Effects and Observables I'm breaking my head on this.

Whats the right combination of operators in this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evantually I solved this just by adding more effects to the equation.
- First effect sends server request... on response sends a UpdateAssignmentSuccess action 
- Second effect listens to UpdateAssignmentSuccess and send a LastUpdatedAssignmentPost action
- Third effect listens to LastUpdatedAssignmentPost action and sends a LastUpdatedAssignment action

```
@Effect()
updateAssignment$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(assignmentActions.AssignmentsActionTypes.UpdateAssignment),
exhaustMap((action) => {
        return this.assignmentDataService.addOrUpdateAssignment([action.payload.postData]).pipe(
            map((assignment) => {
                return new assignmentActions.UpdateAssignmentSuccess(action.payload);
            })
        );
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      return of({
        type: assignmentActions.AssignmentsActionTypes.UpdateAssignmentFailure,
        payload: true
      });
    })
);

@Effect()
updateAssignmentsSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(assignmentActions.AssignmentsActionTypes.UpdateAssignmentSuccess),
map((action:any) => {
  return new assignmentActions.LastUpdatedAssignmentPost(action.payload);
})
);

@Effect()
lastUpdateAssignmentsPost$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(assignmentActions.AssignmentsActionTypes.LastUpdatedAssignmentPost),
map((action:any) => {
  return new assignmentActions.LastUpdatedAssignment(action.payload);
})
);
```

Comment: I do not think splitting it up over multiple effects is the best solution. Have a look at user2216584s idea

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the `payload`, use the last `switchMap` in the observable pipeline of `this.assignmentDataService.addOrUpdateAssignment` API returned observable like this:

```
@Effect()
updateAssignment$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(assignmentActions.AssignmentsActionTypes.UpdateAssignment),
map((action) => {
  return action.payload;
}),
switchMap((payload) => {
  return this.assignmentDataService.addOrUpdateAssignment([payload.postData])
             .pipe(
                switchMap((res) => {
                           return [
                                    new assignmentActions.LastUpdatedAssignmentPost(payload.postData),
                                    new assignmentActions.LastUpdatedAssignment(payload.mergedData),
                                    new assignmentActions.UpdateAssignmentSuccess(payload.mergedData),
                                  ];
                          })             
             );
   })
);
```

Hope it helps.